# Who hired Abaddon?

Tags: plot-explanation, supernatural

In *Supernatural* S08E12 AKA [***As Time Goes By***](http://supernatural-tv-series.wikia.com/wiki/As_Time_Goes_By_(Episode_8.12)) it was mentioned that Abaddon was a hired gun in the series, was it ever revealed who hired Abaddon?

[Larry Ganem described Abaddon as a "hired gun" in "As Time Goes By".](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Abaddon)

Comment: Are you sure about that? Because i dont remeber a scene like that

Comment: @irsha : The old Larry was talking to Sam, after he told him about the key and before Abaddon killed him. Also add it to question, the page I link to also wonders who could have ordered Abaddon around back in 1958

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Abaddon was a Knight Of Hell, thus a "Hired Gun" for Lucifer, since Lucifer was locked in "the Cage" in Hell, unable to walk the earth until the 2000s, when Sam was coerced into unlocking the seals.

So in 1958 Abaddon was working for Lucifer and killed all the "Men of Letters".